# Calling Runspace.Open() inside a TransactionScope changes Transaction.Current and throws exception

Tags: c#, powershell, transactions

If `System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.Runspace.Open()` happens to be inside a `System.Transactions.TransactionScope` it apparently changes Transaction.Current which in turns causes 'System.InvalidOperationException' at transaction's dispose time.

So this:

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
{
    using (var runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace())
    {
        runspace.Open();
    }

    scope.Complete();
}
```

Throws: "Transaction.Current has changed inside of the TransactionScope."

I was wondering if I am missing any crucial parameter in Transaction or Runspace or it has something to do with my power-shell/MSDTC/etc configurations?

Comment: Got same problem. Did you solve it?

Comment: No, I had to redesign my code around it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Had the same issue myself. My Runspace is buried within several nested `TransactionScope` layers. Upon executing `Runspace.Open()`, the Transaction.Current is changed and the Exception is thrown as per the OP's question.

The solution for me was to wrap the code inside another `TransactionScope`, but this time with the `TransactionScopeOption.Suppress` parameter.

```
    using (var transactionScope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Suppress))
        {
            IEnumerable<Object> results = null;

            using (Runspace runSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace())
            {
                runSpace.Open();

                using (Pipeline pipeline = runSpace.CreatePipeline())
                {
                    Command command = new Command(script, true, true);

                    if (parameters != null && parameters.Any())
                        foreach (var param in parameters)
                            command.Parameters.Add(param.Key, param.Value);

                    pipeline.Commands.Add(command);

                    results = pipeline.Invoke();
                }

                runSpace.Close();

                transactionScope.Complete();

                return results;
            }
        }
```

This works perfectly for me. No more exception.